# I am trying to simplify and Modify this Code

Tags: excel, vba

I would like this Code to count the number of incidents in a column starting at Cell A3 and then go the last cell in the column without me having to define it.

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=COUNTIF(Data!R[-2]C[-3]:R[647]C[-3],Data!R[-2]C[-3])"
```

Still new to VBA and learning.

Comment: You can get the lastrow: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))` instead of `647`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to locate the last **used** cell in column C. There are several variations to finding `lastRow`, this is just one of them. Add your code accordingly.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lastCell As Long
lastCell = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Cell  '<<--for finding last active cell reference
lastRow = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row    '<<--for finding last row number
```